# Banners managed by Google Ad Manager don't display in another domain

Tags: google-api, google-ad-manager

we use Google Ad Manager to manage all the banners on our website. It used to be working on two domains: [www.enfsolar.com](http://www.enfsolar.com), and [www.enfrecycling.com](http://www.enfrecycling.com), but it stopped working on [www.enfrecycling.com](http://www.enfrecycling.com) a few months ago.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Eg. this two pages have the exact same code, enfsolar.com can display the banner normally but the other one doesn't:
https://www.enfsolar.com/about?dev=1
https://www.enfrecycling.com/?dev=1

Settings for the two domains is exactly the same, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The 2 pages does not have the exact same code. Are you sure you have active lines items targeting the following adunit : "recycling_banner" ? The working site has a different adunit markup ("Homepage-bottom-728-90"). The GPT setup looks legit on both pages so I would guess something is wrong about deliveries.

Comment: what do you have in GAM > Admin > Policy Center ? 
see documentation : https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/11117554?hl=en&ref_topic=11121694)

Comment: @rabsom Thanks. The test code is exactly the same: 
view-source:https://www.enfsolar.com/about?dev=1  
view-source:https://www.enfrecycling.com/?dev=1

Comment: @rabsom Strange I can't see GAM > Admin > Policy Center on my side, is this because of a permission issue?

Comment: I guess you don't have persmissions on your network... You need to ask a wider acces to your admin

Comment: regarding the delivery : can you confirm there are no specific targetings such as "domain name" on your delivering line item ?

Comment: No "domain name" targetings, and it works before, just stopped working a few months ago.